# Dyalog SALT.Load exceptions "could not fix" for raw function trains

Tags: version-control, apl, dyalog

I've been experimenting with `SALT` but am encountering consistent `Load` problems that seem to only affect raw function-trains.  I hoped for any advice on ensuring all functions `Load` correctly.

To illustrate, in a clear workspace I'll create some example functions for converting hex and octal.  Some are dfns, others are raw trains:

```
FromOct←8⊥⊢
ToOct←(FromOct⍣¯1)
FromHex←{16⊥⍵}
ToHex←{((16⊥⊢)⍣¯1)⍵}
HexToOct←ToOct FromHex
```

Initial salt state:
`⎕SE.SALT.List '/path/to/salt'`
 `Type  Name  Versions  Size  Last Update`

Then `Snap` the workspace:
`⎕SE.SALT.Snap '/path/to/salt -clean -loadfn'`

```
** WARNING: ⎕LX is empty
 #.FromHex  #.FromOct  #.HexToOct  #.ToHex  #.ToOct
```

`⎕SE.SALT.List '/path/to/salt -type'`

```
 Type  Name      Versions  Size  Last Update         
 Fn    FromHex               25  2021/05/18 17:08:32 
 Fn    FromOct               25  2021/05/18 17:08:32 
 Fn    HexToOct              46  2021/05/18 17:08:32 
 Fn    ToHex                 36  2021/05/18 17:08:32 
 Fn    ToOct                 31  2021/05/18 17:08:32 
 Fn    load_ws              537  2021/05/18 17:08:32
```

And check what the `load_ws` function is importing:
`⎕CMD 'cat /path/to/salt/load_ws.dyalog | grep "^ Load''"'`

```
 Load'"/path/to/salt/FromHex" -target=#'       â #.FromHex
 Load'"/path/to/salt/FromOct" -target=#'       â #.FromOct
 Load'"/path/to/salt/HexToOct" -target=#'      â #.HexToOct
 Load'"/path/to/salt/ToHex" -target=#'         â #.ToHex
 Load'"/path/to/salt/ToOct" -target=#'         â #.ToOct
```

In a clear workspace, run the `load_ws`:
`⎕SE.SALT.Load '/path/to/salt/load_ws'`
`load_ws`

```
*** could not fix "/path/to/salt/FromOct.dyalog"
*** could not fix "/path/to/salt/HexToOct.dyalog"
*** could not fix "/path/to/salt/ToOct.dyalog"
```

The dfns load fine, the trains fail.
A ready workaround is to wrap with tradfns or dfns, but this is very undesirable.

Any thoughts on getting SALT to Load these kind of functions correctly?
Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to use SALT, it's obsolete, and I think Dyalog itself recommends you use LINK instead. I'm not sure its worth tracking down why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the current SALT User Guide](https://docs.dyalog.com/18.0/SALT%20User%20Guide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A33%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C368.25%2C0%5D):

> Nameclasses 3.3 (primitive or derived function) and 4.3 (primitive or derived operator) cannot be manipulated using SALT – attempting to do so can result in a loss of data.

As mentioned in [Paul Mansour's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591221/dyalog-salt-load-exceptions-could-not-fix-for-raw-function-trains#comment119471905_67591221), Dyalog Ltd. recommends transitioning from SALT to Link, especially when using Dyalog APL version 18.1, due to be released in the upcoming months. However, note that even [Link does not currently handle tacit functions](https://github.com/Dyalog/link/wiki/Overview#current-limitations):

> Functions, operators and namespaces without text source (`⎕NC` of 3.3 or 4.3, namely derived functions/operators, trains and named primitives), are not supported.

As opposed to SALT, which is not scheduled to receive any major feature additions, this *is* likely to change in the near future.

While it is awkward to wrap tacit functions in tradfns by hand, the [“Lazy” library](https://github.com/abrudz/lazy) makes this a breeze.

Comment: Though I confess to having hoped for some way to get SALT to work, this is a wonderful answer; 
the citations and context help reasoning about the problem and the future. 
Thanks for the clear answer and the alternatives to explore.  I'll look to Link.

Comment: As a P.S., this is an awkwardly public forum for an unrelated comment, 
but I believe I recognize your name, as a RIDE author?  Being new/amateur with dyalog, it is not an overstatement to say RIDE has single-handedly kept me going.  
Thanks for all the work, it makes a big difference.

Comment: @alexgibbs I'm but a minor contributor to RIDE. As for the forum, you may want to visit [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405) Stack Exchange chat room.